# Valid well-formed formulae in predicate calculus?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Which one of the following well-formed formulae in predicate calculus is NOT valid?

1. $(\forall x~p(x) \implies \forall x~q(x)) \implies( \exists x~\lnot p(x) \lor \forall x~q(x))$
2. $(\exists x~p(x) \lor \exists x~q(x))     \implies  \exists x~(p(x) \lor q(x)) $
3. $ \exists x~(p(x) \land q(x))             \implies( \exists x~p(x) \land \exists x~q(x))$
4. $ \forall x~(p(x) \lor q(x))              \implies( \forall x~p(x) \lor \forall x~q(x))$

---

My attempt :

Let $p(x)=\text{x is even}$ and
$q(x)=\text{x is odd}$ in set of natural number. Then :

1. True, and converse is also true.
2. True, and converse is also true.
3. True, and converse is not true.
4. False, but converse is true.

> Can you explain in formal way, please?

Comment: Trying a concrete example can be used to show that a formula is _not_ valid nut not that it _is_ -- so the only thing you learn from the attempt is that (4) is not valid.

Comment: (The other three are _in fact_ valid, but your single example doesn't prove that they are).

Comment: I dont think the use of quantifiers in the implication is something right... but Im unsure about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P$ and $Q$ are unary relations, so you can model each of them as sets $P_s$ and $Q_s$, where $P(x)$ iff $x \in P_s$ and $Q(x)$ iff $x \in Q_s$.  Let $W$ be every object in the universe.

So translate each statement into sets:

> 1. $(\forall x~p(x) \implies \forall x~q(x)) \implies( \exists x~\lnot p(x) \lor \forall x~q(x))$

Convert the $\lor$ to $\implies$, you get:

$$(\forall x~p(x) \implies \forall x~q(x)) \implies( \lnot \exists x~\lnot p(x) \implies \forall x~q(x))$$
$$(\forall x~p(x) \implies \forall x~q(x)) \implies( \forall x~p(x) \implies \forall x~q(x))$$

So the formula is valid if, for any model where $(\forall x~p(x) \implies \forall x~q(x))$ holds, that $(\forall x~p(x) \implies \forall x~q(x))$ also holds.

> 2. $(\exists x~p(x) \lor \exists x~q(x))     \implies  \exists x~(p(x) \lor q(x)) $

If $P_s$ is not empty or $Q_s$ is not empty, then $P_s \cup Q_s$ is not empty.  Fairly easy to establish that this holds for any model.

> 3. $ \exists x~(p(x) \land q(x))             \implies( \exists x~p(x) \land \exists x~q(x))$

If $P_s \cap Q_s$ is nonempty then $P_s$ is nonempty and $Q_s$ is nonempty.  Anything will model this.

> 4. $ \forall x~(p(x) \lor q(x))              \implies( \forall x~p(x) \lor \forall x~q(x))$

If $P_s \cup Q_s = W$ , then $P_s = W$ or $Q_s = W$.  This is clearly not true for any choice of $P_s$ and $Q_s$.  In fact the only times it will be true is:

- when $P_s = W$, meaning $P(x) = \text{True}$, or
- when $Q_s = W$, meaning $Q(x) = \text{True}$, or
- when $P_s \cap Q_s \ne W$, that is, when there is a value of $x$ where both $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ don't hold.

Otherwise the choice of $P()$ and $Q()$ will not model (4).